# EXTJS reuse alias become nonfunctional tab

Tags: javascript, extjs

[image]

i have default 4 tabs with vehicle manage, driver manage, location manage, route manage.
and i have a toolbar able to recreate the Vehicle Manage tab 
[image]

this is the toolbar i have mention, so when we create a new vehicle manage tab, **will cause the all tabs unfunctional**. Maybe i Reuse the gridpanel in new Vehicle Manage?

here is my example code:

**vehicle.js**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyVehicleGridPanel', {
   extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
   id : 'mygridpanel',
   //renderTo : 'vehiclebody',
   alias: 'widget.mygrid',
   header: false,
   store: UserStore,
   multiSelect: false,
   columns: [
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    dataIndex: '_id',

                    text: 'Vehicle ID'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    width: 126,
                    dataIndex: 'Plat_No',
                    text: 'Plat Number'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    width: 200,
                    dataIndex: 'Name',
                    text: 'Added By'
                }
]
})
```

when user clicked the toorbar will use the alias `mygrid` again.

this is my toolbar code:

```
var BtnVehicle = Ext.getCmp('BtnVehicle');
    BtnVehicle.on('click', function(){
        tabs.add({
            closable: true,
            xtype : 'mygrid',
            //html: '<div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#cccccc;"><iframe src="vehicle/vehicle.html" frameborder=0 scrolling="no" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></iframe></div>',
            iconCls: 'bus32',
            title: 'Vehicle Manage'
        }).show();
    })
```

whenever user able to create unlimit tab with the same design same gridpanel.

how come when create a second same `xtype: 'mygrid'` then the tab will become nonfunctional?

Comment: don't use `id` in GridPanel `e.g id : 'mygridpanel'`

Comment: @MMT if dont have `id` how i can get the gridpanel like `var grid = Ext.getCmp('mygridpanel')` ? have other way?

Comment: check [Ext.ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery)

Comment: @MMT please post as answer, i will mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `id` from `GridPanel` config, instead use `itemId` & 
search Components within Ext.ComponentManager (globally) or a specific Ext.container.Container on the document with a similar syntax to a CSS selector using `Ext.ComponentQuery`

refer [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery)